# How to create a custom callback

Tags: javascript

I have a function that done some asynch operations :

```
function funcAsynch() {
    // asynch operations
}
```

well, I'd like calling this function, and declare a callback to execute when all asynch operations are finished.

Somethings like

```
customCallback(funcAsynch(), function () { 
    alert("all asynch operations are finished") 
});
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a parameter for your `funcAsynch()` function.

```
function funcAsynch(callback) {
    // asynch operations
    // invoke callback() when asynch is done
}
```

And pass the callback function to that parameter.

```
funcAsynch(function () { 
    alert("all asynch operations are finished");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    // ...

    // Call the callback
    callback('stuff', 'goes', 'here');
}

function foo(a, b, c) {
    // I'm the callback
    alert(a + " " + b + " " + c);
}

doSomething(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little helper function:

```
function asyncFn() {
  var readyList = [],
       isReady = false;

  function emitReady() {
    isReady = true;
    var i = 0,
        len = readyList.length;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
      emit( readyList[i] );
    }
  }
  function emit( fn ) {
    fn();
  }
  function ready( fn ) {
      if ( !isReady ) {
        readyList.push( fn );
      }
      else {
        emit( fn );
      }
    }

  return {
    ready: ready,
    emitReady: emitReady
  };
}
```

---

**Usecase 1**

```
function F() {
    var async = asyncFn();

    async.ready(function() {
        // Called when emitReady is called
    });

    async.emitReady();
}
```

**Usecase 2**

```
function customAsync() {
  var async = asyncFn();

  /*
    Async stuff going on here....
  */
  setTimeout(function() {
    async.emitReady();
  }, 500);

  return async;
}

function customCallback(def, callback) {
  def.ready(callback);
}


customCallback(customAsync(), function() {
  console.log("async is operated");
});
```

---

Just one approach...